# How can a float design achieve this table-like result?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm usually a Web technologies enthusiast, and I'm all for the no-tables-design thing, but right now, it's somewhat pissing me off. :/

I'm trying to achieve something that would have been extremely easy with tables, but that seems overly complex/impossible using floating elements. Look at the following:

```
+-----------------+ +-------+
|                 | |       |
|    #contents    | | #info |
|                 | |       |
|                 | +-------+
+-----------------+
```

Where `#info` has a fixed width, and must be floating right to `#contents`. `#contents` should take whatever's left of the width.

In the simple design where both `#contents` and `#info` are present, this isn't too complex. They are both fixed-width, have the `float:left` property, and fit very well.

However, on certain pages, `#info` won't be present. When it's the case, obviously, `#contents` doesn't scale to fit all the page.

The most obvious solution was to give `#contents` no fixed width so it'd scale, and change `#info` to be `float:right`. Past the minor other changes it required, it didn't have exactly the desired behavior, since it breaks the column-like layout when `#contents` is taller than `#info`:

```
+-----------------+ +-------+
|                 | |       |
|    #contents    | | #info |
|                 | |       |
|                 | +-------+
|                 +---------+
|                           |
+---------------------------+
```

Even worse, inside `#contents`, there are other `<div>`s with the `border-bottom` property set, and the border passes right through `#info` too in the following fashion:

```
+-----------------+ +-------+
|                 | |       |
|    #contents    | | #info |
|-----------------|-|-------|
|                 | +-------+
|                 +---------+
|                           |
+---------------------------+
```

**So, considering all this, how can I give `#info` a fixed width, have it float to the right of `#contents`, but keep the column-like design and have `#contents` occupy the whole screen when `#info` isn't there, all of this making sure there are no visual artifacts, and without resorting to more than one stylesheet?**

This would be the desired result on a page where both `#contents` and `#info` are present:

```
+-----------------+ +-------+
|                 | |       |
|    #contents    | | #info |
|-----------------| |       |
|                 | +-------+
|-----------------|
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

And this is the desired result on a page where only `#contents` is present:

```
+---------------------------+
|         #contents         |
|---------------------------|
|                           |
|---------------------------|
|                           |
+---------------------------+
```

I hope this wasn't too confusing. I'm out of brain power.

Comment: http://giveupandusetables.com/

Comment: @Ben: that's a better way to state it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emailed my web teacher about it, and the answer is quite simple. It doesn't work with Internet Explorer (at least version 6), but it degrades nicely for my case.

With `#info` set to `float:right`, it suffices to have `#contents` set with the property `overflow:hidden`. And voilà.

Comment: Why don't you invite your web teacher to SO and have them earn their own reputation points ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Float your #content div too, it stops it from leaking like you're having, and it will fill the entire page when #info is gone. If when you dont have #info you can change #content somehow, #content could have a position relative and some right padding, with a position absolute in #info to fill its place.

Comment: Setting #contents to float indeed stops the leak, but without a fixed width, it takes as much room as it needs; and doing so pushes #info under it instead of besides it when #contents can take 100% of the width.