# 2 divs side-by-side, one floated - how do I make the other fit next to it without overlapping?

Tags: html, css, width

I have had the following problem for a while and I am really not sure how to solve it.

The problem can currently be observed here: http://www.androidpolice.com/2009/11/16/the-not-so-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-my-list-of-20-problems-with-htc-hero/ - feel free to use this for Firebugging.

There are 2 notions here: a **table of contents (toc)** and **notes**. A note usually takes 100% of the post width and everything is fine.

*However*, when a note appears next to a toc, the **toc starts overlapping and covering the note** (I set `z-index:1` on the toc because otherwise the note covered it, which was even worse).

It's interesting to point out that the text of the note doesn't get covered by the toc - only the note div itself does.

In IE7, it's even worse - the note div jumps down to under the toc and leaves a lot of empty space (2nd screenshot).

**So, how can I solve this?** The ideal solution would have the note div occupy 100% of the visible space - i.e. it would resize itself to fit right next to the toc when needed.

Here are some screenshots for future reference:
[image]

In IE7:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had [about the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346157/how-can-a-float-design-achieve-this-table-like-result). Though I can't help for your IE7-specific issue, using `overflow: hidden` on the left column did the trick for the layout overlapping (and did not hide data). Specifically, in your case, you need to:

1. Remove the `position:relative` code on the relevant `.toc` and `.note` elements;
2. Set `width:auto` on the `.note` elements;
3. Set `overflow:hidden` on the `.note` elements.

Note that this will not work under IE6, but meh, it's IE6. It'll look ugly, but [people using IE6 these days are forced to](http://web.archive.org/web/20120615173309/http://about.digg.com:80/blog/much-ado-about-ie6), and besides, it's not making the website unusable.

---

The result in Safari:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look after dinner.

Comment: Brilliant! It works in IE7 this way too. I didn't even have to remove the position - the main parts were `width:auto` and `overflow:hidden` on `.note` and `width:auto` on `.note div`. Thank you.